# Accessing API using Python

Tags: python, api

I was trying to retrieve data from an API and i was receiving

**'set' object has no attribute 'items'**

This is my api.py and i have import it to my views

```
import json
import urllib
import urllib2
import pycurl

def get_resources(request, filter, endpoint, lookup):
    headers = {'X-Auth-Token:%s' % request.user.token, 'Content-Type:application/json'}
    data = urllib.urlencode(filter)
    url = endpoint+lookup
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    result = json.loads(response.read())
    return result
```

and my views.py is like this

```
def indexView(request):
    resources = json.dumps(get_resources(request,{}, api_endpoint, '/v2/meters'))
    return HttpResponse(resources, mimetype='application/json')
```

I know that i was doing wrong here, I hope someone who could help me thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
headers = {'X-Auth-Token:%s' % request.user.token,
           'Content-Type:application/json'}
```

defines a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set). And it should probably be a dictionary (which has `:` somewhere in after which follows the value for the key before the `:`)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
headers = {'X-Auth-Token': request.user.token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```